# attachment body of all the account records

Tags: apex, soql

How to Query to Attachments of Account Object.
I need to fetch the attachment body of all the account records.

I tried to fetch by SOQL Query but it is not working

```
Select Id,Name,Body,ParentId from Attachment where ParentId Like 'a07%'
```

Is there any alternative to fetch the attachment body of all the Account records?

Answer (score 0):

You can fetch all the Attachments for all the account using nested query.
First you have to query on account object and also do the query on child attachment at the same time.

For reference please take a help from below dummy code

```
list<account> accList = [Select id , (Select Id,Name,Body,ParentId from Attachments) from Account];
for(account acc : accList  ){
if(acc.Attachments.size >0){
for(Attachment att : acc.Attachments)
//fill the string list with the attachment body
   }
}
```

I hope this may help you.

Thanks

Comment: While i am tring this , i am getting this error "Binary fields cannot be selected in join queries"

Comment: Ok thanks,

I got it, body is a binary field in Attachment. So you can do query on Attachment with Parent.Type where Parent.Type = 'Account'.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Parent.Type` field from the Attachment object.

```
List<Attachment> attachmentList = [Select Id, Name, ContentType, ParentId, Description, Body from Attachment Where Parent.Type = 'Account'];
```

I'd suggest you append an `AND` clause to the above SOQL. Retrieving attachments across all Accounts in an environment may lead you to exceed SOQL limits.